# NullReferenceException error on Server Only using Entity Framework and MySQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm receiving a 500 server error when calling a webservice using ASP.NET and JQuery.  I view the response:

Part of the response:

```
{"Message":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","StackTrace":"
```

The line that throws it is:

```
 db.SaveChanges();
```

On my local computer when I run the site it works, it only throws error on my Windows Server 2012 on AWS.  The other thing is that I can't debug it remotely.

The db is initialized and the data that I add to the table is initialized too I've double checked the data that is being entered to the table, even put data manually to make sure, but error still persists.

**id** variable is retrieved from the function argument, if is not initialized the code doesn't run.

CODE:

```
 using (siteEntities db = new siteEntities()){
                         {
var c_weekly = (from weekly in db.counters_weekly
    where weekly.product_id == id
    select weekly).SingleOrDefault();

if (c_weekly == null) {
    counters_weekly cw = new counters_weekly();
    cw.count = 0;
    cw.product_id = id;
    cw.year = DateTime.UtcNow.Year;
    cw.week_number = GetIso8601WeekOfYear(DateTime.Now);

    db.counters_weekly.Add(cw);
     db.SaveChanges(); <== THROWS ERROR!!!!

    c_weekly = (from weekly in db.counters_weekly
    where weekly.product_id == id
    select weekly).SingleOrDefault();
}
long weekly_old_count = c_weekly.count;
c_weekly.count = weekly_old_count + Global.DataCounters[id];
db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Generated by entity Framrwork:

```
public partial class counters_weekly
{
    public decimal id { get; set; }
    public long product_id { get; set; }
    public int week_number { get; set; }
    public long count { get; set; }
    public int year { get; set; }
}
```

Any explanation. If there was an easy way to debug online I would have done it. Really need your help on this one. Thanks.

DB: MySQL

Server: Windows Server 2012 EC2 AWS

Using: Latest .NET Connector

Comment: Show definition of `counters_weekly`.

Comment: Where do you initialize the object `db`? Show the WHOLE RELEVANT part of your code please.

Comment: The code is huge, but the db is initialized (added to the question)

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: I put " if (db != null)" before the call and it's not null, because svechanges is still being excecuted